# Spark SQL JSON Boolean Evaluation

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have the example JSON Schema (cut off due to size):

```
 |-- LinearScheduleResult: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Build: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- EndTimestamp: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Errors: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- RequestId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Schedule: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Airings: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- AiringTime: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- AiringType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- CC: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- CallLetters: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Category: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Channel: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Color: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Copy: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- DSS: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- DVS: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Dolby: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Duration: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- DvbTriplet: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- EpisodeTitle: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- HD: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- HDLevel: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- IconAvailable: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- InstanceId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- LetterBox: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- MovieRating: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- ParentNetworkId: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- ProgramId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- SAP: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- SL: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- SeriesId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- ServiceId: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- ShowingType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- SourceDisplayName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- SourceId: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- SourceLongName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Sports: boolean (nullable = true)
```

When I do the following:

```
results = sqlContext.sql("SELECT LinearScheduleResult.Schedule.Airings.Sports from tv")
```

It returns:

```
[Row(Sports=[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False])]
```

When I do something more complex like:

```
results = sqlContext.sql("SELECT LinearScheduleResult.Schedule.Airings from tv where LinearScheduleResult.Schedule.Airings.Sports = 'False'")
```

It will never return anything, I've tried 'false', false, 0, FALSE, and plenty more combinations.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Airings is an array, you need to explode the row first. Something like:

```
select a from tv 
  lateral view explode(LinearScheduleResult.Schedule.Airings) a as a 
  where a.Sports = false
```

You will have to use HiveSqlContext for that.

See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+LateralView

Comment: Or you can drop down to regular rdd computation